# Collection Object operator for @firstObject Key-value coding KVC

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-coding

I'm often required to retrieve the 1st object belonging to a Set. (Using that object as a representative of that set.)

I envision a Collection Object operator, akin to the

```
@unionOfObjects
```

BUT clearly

```
@firstObject
```

Is it possible to create such a Collection operator!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's no way to define custom collection operators. However, due to some internal magic there is a funny solution:

```
    NSSet *testSet = [NSSet setWithArray:@[@"one", @(1)]];

    id object = [testSet valueForKey:@"@anyObject"];
    NSLog(@"anyObject (%@): %@", NSStringFromClass([object class]), object);
```

**UPD:** Forgot to mention another handy trick: you can use `@lastObject` on `NSArray`!

Comment: the `anyObject` might work. thanks. ill give it a shot. on initial viewing, if you have the nsset why not just do [testSet anyObject] versus [testSet valueForKey@"anyObject"]. essentially, it looks like some accessor methods (lastObject, anyObject) for Sets and Arrays are key value coded.

Comment: @GabeRainbow, your question was about using collection operators. You can definitely use anyObject. Warning, valueForKey:@"anyObject" will not work. valueForKey:@"@anyObject" will. This is due to some implementation details of collection operators.

Comment: thanks for the clarification there. i noted that @"" misspelling in the Apple documents that must cause some headaches. For sure anyObject  will work for my purpose, since Im seeking any representative object in the set and not a particular one, first last whatever.